# Corresponding conservation law to Lagrangian symmetry

Tags: homework-and-exercises, conservation-laws, symmetry, noethers-theorem, string

Using this Lagrangian : $L=\frac{1}{2}\left(u_t^2-u_x^2\right)$, which describes a simple string.  I know about these vector fields which are the symmetries of this Lagrangian $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$$ 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial u}$$
I also found that the Lie derivative is zero for this vector field $\xi=t\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+x\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$
then I calculated the Noether current $$\Phi\left(\xi\right)=dx\left(\frac{1}{2}t\left(u_t^2+u_x^2\right)+x\,u_t\,u_x\right)-dt\left(\frac{1}{2}x\left(u_t^2+u_x^2\right)-t\,u_xu_t\right)$$
But I have no idea what the corresponding conservation law to this symmetry is, what is the physical meaning? Can someone help please? It is also possible that I did the calculation wrong and the field isn´t a symmetry but I checked multiple times.

Comment: Is Lorentz boost the same as Lorentz transformation ?

Comment: It's the special case. The Lorentz group consists of all linear transformations of $[w,x,y,z]$ preserving $w^2 - x^2 - y^2 - z^2$ but these transformations include not just the distinctive "boosts" like $[w,x,y,z] \to [\gamma\cdot(w - \beta x), \gamma\cdot(x - \beta w), y, z]$ but also rotations of the 3D subspace, parity transforms like $[w,x,y,z] \to [-w, x, y, z],$ and compositions of these other basic transforms, like "4-screws".

Comment: Yeah I see it now, thank you. But I still don´t know what is the conservation law ?

Comment: The physical meaning of the conservation law is the relativistic corresponding of the theorem of center of mass. Unfortunately I do not have time to enter into the details...